# Gulp - can't set multiple relative destinations

Tags: gulp

I have a multisite I'm wanting to process using GulpJS. I've hit a snag outputting the SCSS files to relative "css" directories in one task. I've tried multiple examples of setting the base directory but to no avail. Maybe I'm missing something.

Folder structure is:

```
root
|
theme1
|   |
|   scss
|   |   |
|   |   changes.scss
|   |   common.scss
|   |   login.scss
|   css
|   |  | 
|   |  [Theme1 files go here]
theme2
|   |
|   scss
|   |   |
|   |   changes.scss
|   |   common.scss
|   |   login.scss
|   css
|   |  |
|   |  [Theme2 files go here]
etc.
```

Code is:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  var filter = gulpFilter(['*/**/.css.map']);

  return gulp.src('*/scss/{changes,common,login}.scss', {base: './*/' })
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(filter)
    .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'android 4'] }) ]))
    .pipe(filter.restore())
    .pipe(changed('*/**/scss')) // Ignore unchanged files
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'css' ) )
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(header(banner, { pkg : pkg } ))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'css' ) )
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
   });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @dyaa I already did! I rewarded you with the bounty =) The question isn't mine, so I can't accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

i guess that the [running tasks per folder recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md) may help.

Also the following the ideas in the recipe, and oversimplifying your sample just to give the idea, this can be a solution:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    path = require('path'),
    merge = require('merge-stream');

var folders = ['httpdocs-site1', 'httpdocs-site2', 'httpdocs-site3'];

gulp.task('default', function(){

    var tasks = folders.map(function(element){
        return gulp.src(element + '/media/sass/**/*.scss', {base: element + '/media/sass'})
            // ... other steps ...
            .pipe(gulp.dest(element + '/media/css'));
    });

    return merge(tasks);
});
```

Comment: Hi @dyaa. Thanks for the reply. I've tried implementing your example but it seems to be outputting the same thing to each folder. Code is: `var folders = ['desktop/common', 'desktop/theme-a', 'desktop/theme-b', 'desktop/theme-c'];

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    var filter = gulpFilter(['**/*.css.map']);
    var tasks = folders.map(function(element){
        return gulp.src(element + scssDir + '/**/*.scss')
            //... tasks
            .pipe(gulp.dest(element + cssDir))
            .pipe(notify({message: 'Styles task complete'}));
    });
    return merge(tasks);
});`